# I need a font to fit my page nicely or any good suggestion

Tags: math-mode, fonts

I want to write this in such a font size so that it fits A4 page but I'm not getting that.

I used tiny font but not getting all the terms the same.

```
\begin{align*}
& \tiny{S(A-\lambda E)T} \tiny{=\begin{bmatrix*}[r]A_P& A_{PR}& A_{PQ}\\0&A_{R}&A_{RQ}\\0&0&A_Q \end{bmatrix*}-\lambda \begin{bmatrix*}[r]E_P& E_{PR}& E_{PQ}\\0&E_{R}&E_{RQ}\\0&0&E_Q \end{bmatrix*}}.\\ 
& \tiny{\Rightarrow[P_2,R_2,Q_2]^{-1}(A-\lambda E)[P_1,R_1,Q_1]=\begin{bmatrix*}[r]A_P& A_{PR}& A_{PQ}\\0&A_{R}&A_{RQ}\\0&0&A_Q \end{bmatrix*}-\lambda \begin{bmatrix*}[r]E_P& E_{PR}& E_{PQ}\\0&E_{R}&E_{RQ}\\0&0&E_Q \end{bmatrix*}}.\\ 
&\tiny{\Rightarrow (A-\lambda E)[P_1,R_1,Q_1]=[P_2,R_2,Q_2]\begin{bmatrix*}[r]A_P& A_{PR}& A_{PQ}\\0&A_{R}&A_{RQ}\\0&0&A_Q \end{bmatrix*}- \lambda[P_2,R_2,Q_2] \begin{bmatrix*}[r]E_P& E_{PR}& E_{PQ}\\0&E_{R}&E_{RQ}\\0&0&E_Q \end{bmatrix*}}\\
&\tiny{\Rightarrow [AP_1,AR_1,AQ_1]-\lambda[EP_1,ER_1,EQ_1]}=\tiny{[P_2A_P,P_2A_{PR}+R_2A_R,P_2A_{PQ}+R_2A_{RQ}+Q_2A_Q]-\lambda [P_2E_P,P_2E_{PR}+R_2E_R,P_2E_{PQ}+R_2E_{RQ}+Q_2E_{Q}]}.\\
\end{align*}
```

Comment: a) please add a full compilable MWE (from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` in order to help us to help you.  b) Choosing such a small fontsize, you have to provide a magnifying glass to your gentle reader, that he can read those lines.  c) depending on the circumstances, you might have a normal math environment encapsuled in a `\resizsebox` or `\scalebox`to fit that math content on a given space, which leads to point b). :-(

Comment: What's the default font size of your document, which font family do you use (if not Computer Modern), and how wide is the text block? (You've stated the paper size, but you haven't indicated how wide the margins are.)

Comment: you can not use size change commands in math (that must surely have produced errors? if you must use a single `\tiny` before the math (although it will not be readable at that size)

Comment: I am using \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

Comment: @riemann - And how wide are the page margins?

Comment: how to know that? \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}% for 'align*' environment and '\stackrel' macro
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{bm}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{stackrel}
\theoremstyle{definition}

Answer (score 5):

Rather than use a tiny font size to make the equations "fit" and risk making the material undecipherable, you should introduce a few more line breaks.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for 'bmatrix*' env.
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
&S(A-\lambda E)T 
=\begin{bmatrix*}[r]A_P& A_{PR}& A_{PQ}\\0&A_{R}&A_{RQ}\\0&0&A_Q \end{bmatrix*}
-\lambda \begin{bmatrix*}[r]E_P& E_{PR}& E_{PQ}\\0&E_{R}&E_{RQ}\\0&0&E_Q \end{bmatrix*}\\ 
&\Rightarrow [P_2,R_2,Q_2]^{-1}(A-\lambda E)[P_1,R_1,Q_1]
=\begin{bmatrix*}[r]A_P& A_{PR}& A_{PQ}\\0&A_{R}&A_{RQ}\\0&0&A_Q \end{bmatrix*}
-\lambda \begin{bmatrix*}[r]E_P& E_{PR}& E_{PQ}\\0&E_{R}&E_{RQ}\\0&0&E_Q \end{bmatrix*}\\ 
&\Rightarrow (A-\lambda E)[P_1,R_1,Q_1] =
\!\begin{aligned}[t]
&[P_2,R_2,Q_2]\begin{bmatrix*}[r]A_P& A_{PR}& A_{PQ}\\0&A_{R}&A_{RQ}\\0&0&A_Q \end{bmatrix*}\\
&\quad-\lambda[P_2,R_2,Q_2] \begin{bmatrix*}[r]E_P& E_{PR}& E_{PQ}\\0&E_{R}&E_{RQ}\\0&0&E_Q \end{bmatrix*}
\end{aligned}\\[2ex]
&\Rightarrow 
\begin{multlined}[t] [AP_1,AR_1,AQ_1]-\lambda[EP_1,ER_1,EQ_1]=\\[1ex]
[P_2A_P,P_2A_{PR}+R_2A_R,P_2A_{PQ}+R_2A_{RQ}+Q_2A_Q]\\
-\lambda [P_2E_P,P_2E_{PR}+R_2E_R,P_2E_{PQ}+R_2E_{RQ}+Q_2E_{Q}]\end{multlined}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```